# A word for someone succeeding at something due to a series of coincidences

Tags: phrase-requests

"Lucky" can apply to any fortunate situation.

What I'm thinking is a situation where two people of equal skill face off in a competition of sorts. They have never faced each other before and have no knowledge of the other person's play-style. Yet one of them defeats the other with ease due to their play-style coincidentally countering the other's. When player A does Z, player B does Y simultaneously, over the course of dozens of engagements, which happens to favor player B.

"Lucky" feels too generic a word for this situation.

Comment: _The harder I practice, the luckier I get_

Comment: "their play-style coincidentally countering the other's." does not sound like a series of coincidences. It sounds more like skillful maneuvering or outwitting.

Comment: This reminds me of Rock Paper Scissors championships. Look that up for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

**serendipity** from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/serendipity):

> The occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or beneficial way.